# Not able to print from an asp.net web application when accessing it through mobile or tab

Tags: printing

I am accessing a web application through tab, but printing options are not working, when I am clicking the print button the print dialog box is not opening.
I want it to print the page using the default printer in the network.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Perhaps an animated one?

Comment: I have used window.print() on button click, its working when accessing the application from PC's chrome browser but the same is not working when accessing it from mobile or tablet's chrome browser